# Getting FreeBSD to recognize a 8th SATA drive?

Tags: freebsd, hard-disk, bsd, sata

I have a TrueNAS Mini E (running FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p14), which comes pre-configured with seven drives: 4 3.5" for main storage, two SSD caches, and a boot disk. The hardware has two more SATA ports on it, so I plugged in an 8th drive. But I can't get FreeBSD to recognize the drive. It doesn't show up in `dmesg` nor in `camcontrol devlist`.

I've tried different SATA cables, rebooting, (although the main drives are hot-swappable), etc. I’m not sure if I need to tell FreeBSD to look for more attached drives, or what.

```
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series System Agent (rev 11)
00:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Error Registers (rev 11)
00:05.0 Generic system peripheral [0807]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Root Complex Event Collector (rev 11)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev 11)
00:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SMBus Contoller - Host (rev 11)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SATA Controller 0 (rev 11)
00:14.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SATA Controller 1 (rev 11)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Integrated LAN Root Port #0 (rev 11)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Integrated LAN Root Port #1 (rev 11)
00:18.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series ME HECI 1 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series LPC or eSPI (rev 11)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series Power Management Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SMBus controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor C3000 Series SPI Controller (rev 11)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 04)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE (rev 11)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE (rev 11)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE (rev 11)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE (rev 11)

# camcontrol devlist                         
<WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82>    at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (pass0,ada0)
<WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82>    at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (pass1,ada1)
<WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82>    at scbus2 target 0 lun 0 (pass2,ada2)
<WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82>    at scbus3 target 0 lun 0 (pass3,ada3)
<Micron 5200 MTFDDAK480TDC D1MU020>  at scbus4 target 0 lun 0 (pass4,ada4)
<Micron 5200 MTFDDAK480TDC D1MU020>  at scbus5 target 0 lun 0 (pass5,ada5)
<AHCI SGPIO Enclosure 2.00 0001>   at scbus6 target 0 lun 0 (pass6,ses0)
<16GB SATA Flash Drive SFDK004A>   at scbus7 target 0 lun 0 (pass7,ada6)
<AHCI SGPIO Enclosure 2.00 0001>   at scbus8 target 0 lun 0 (pass8,ses1)

# dmesg | grep SATA
ahci0: <Intel Denverton AHCI SATA controller> port 0xe090-0xe097,0xe080-0xe083,0xe040-0xe05f mem 0xdfb36000-0xdfb37fff,0xdfb3d000-0xdfb3d0ff,0xdfb3c000-0xdfb3c7ff irq 20 at device 19.0 on pci0
ahci1: <Intel Denverton AHCI SATA controller> port 0xe070-0xe077,0xe060-0xe063,0xe020-0xe03f mem 0xdfb34000-0xdfb35fff,0xdfb3b000-0xdfb3b0ff,0xdfb3a000-0xdfb3a7ff irq 21 at device 20.0 on pci0
ses0: (none) in 'Slot 00', SATA Slot: scbus0 target 0
ses0: (none) in 'Slot 01', SATA Slot: scbus1 target 0
ses0: (none) in 'Slot 02', SATA Slot: scbus2 target 0
ses0: (none) in 'Slot 03', SATA Slot: scbus3 target 0
ses0: (none) in 'Slot 04', SATA Slot: scbus4 target 0
ses0: (none) in 'Slot 05', SATA Slot: scbus5 target 0
ada0: <WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada0: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)
ses1: (none) in 'Slot 05', SATA Slot: scbus7 target 0
ada1: <WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada1: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)
ada2: <WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada2: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)
ada3: <WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0 82.00A82> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada3: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)
ada4: <Micron 5200 MTFDDAK480TDC D1MU020> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada4: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)
ada5: <Micron 5200 MTFDDAK480TDC D1MU020> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada5: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)
ada6: <16GB SATA Flash Drive SFDK004A> ACS-2 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada6: 600.000MB/s transfers (SATA 3.x, UDMA5, PIO 512bytes)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your extra sata ports might not be bios enabled or supported by the kernel?  Dunno your hardware.  To test things, get something that does USB to SATA (such as en enclosure or temporary cable).  Use this to verify that your drive works.  If your drive works, then those sata ports don't work for you.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to come back and comment. That does seem to be the case. After figuring out how to get into the BIOS, there was no way to enable those extra ports. Emailing support for the TrueNAS and for the board maker pretty much confirms their custom BIOS explicitly prevents this.